# Autofill with 2 dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that contains a number of different dates. Each has 2 different hours:

[image]
How can I fill these dates down the page without manually typing them. When I go to drag down the page I get a copy of what I am dragging.

How can I go about this without having to type each date?

Comment: Please expand a little. Is your data 2 columns wide or is the date and time in one cell.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a formula and just adding 1 to the cell 2 cells above.

ie. cell B5 `=B3+1`.

Copy this formula down and if you want to freeze the cells just copy and paste value.